# Spark notebooks is quicker than executing a jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit, spark-notebook

I have finished some code in spark notebook, I tried to move it into a real project, and use `sbt` to generate a **jar**, then use the `spark-submit` to execute it.

*Problem:* It takes just **10 minutes** to get the result in spark notebooks, but it takes almost **3 hours** to get the result when I use the command spark-submit.

*Info:* I configured the spark, scala version, and parameters(master url, execution core/memory, etc.) are all the same between notebooks and spark-submit.

Suspect 1: maybe because of the logs(LogFactory.getLog().info("xxxx"))? which make the program take too time to print them or save them ?

Suspect 2: maybe because of the code? I didn't do any big changes to the code of notebook, just create a function, put the code inside and run it. Should I do some partitions or something?

Comment: Here's a way to test what's going on: Open a notebook with a fresh spark session (presumably this takes ~1 minute), check your YARN or Spark UI to make sure nothing has run yet. Run the code in the notebook and look at the resources used in the UI (# of Tasks, # of executors, cache usage, time taken per task, etc). Then run the same code through spark-submit jar and see what stages are taking longer. Do they have the same # of tasks, did they have the same DAG execution plan, did they take the same amount of time per task, etc?